# When click Cancel button on form, do not run On Exit code on a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

On my form, the first field has to be entered, so I have an On Exit command.  Since it also checks to see if the value exists in my table, I want it to check right away - is it blank (thus require data to be put into field) OR does it already exist.  My question has to do with the first part - is it blank.

On this form, I also have a Cancel button.  When the user click Cancel, I want it to close the form without saving any of the data.

Problem - If the user doesn't enter anything in the first field and clicks Cancel, it's running the On Exit code requiring data to be entered into the first field - which they don't have to because they are cancelling.  I'm getting a Run-time error '2585'.

Is there anyway to have the Cancel code stop the On Exit code from running? Any other ideas?

Here is my code for Cancel:

```
Private Sub CancelFormButton_Click()
  Me.Undo
  DoCmd.OpenForm "fmuMainMenu"
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmVetNewMainForm"
End Sub
```

Here is part of my On Exit code for the field:

```
If IsNull(Me.txtSSN) Then

  strMsg = "Social Security Number Must Not Be Left Blank!" & vbCrLf
  strMsg = strMsg & "Do you want to add new veteran's record?" & vbCrLf

  If MsgBox(strMsg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Go to Record?") = vbYes Then

    Me.txtSSN.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

  Else

    Me.Undo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "fmuMainMenu"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmVetNewMainForm"

  End If

Else
  'RUNS THE REST OF CODE
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

OnExit events occur everytime you leave the textbox, even a simple tab or click to go to another combo box or select some text will trigger it. 
You may want to try the code in the AfterUpdates.

and try a ,nosave after the close form command...

In addition, any checks to ensure a field is filled/has data is usually encouraged to be performed in the Form_BeforeUpdate section... Or so I have been advised

Comment: Had tried that nosave (acSaveNo). Didn't work. I also tried Cancel = True. No luck. For checking the SSN, I can move the part that checks if it's in system to AfterUpdate, but for part that checks if it's blank, it's blank so there's no update... I want it to check right away if it's blank when the user exits the SSN field to make sure the user typed something in that field so they don't enter a bunch of data that already exists. Make sense?  How to get the stupid Cancel to work if they don't type anything in SSN field.. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Leave the code out of the onExit. That's causing the issue. 
Instead a loop in the AfterUpdate event of the same text box that prompts the user if they want to leave the field blank. & warns them of the issue.
on cancel click; You may wish to check for duplicate SSN if there is such a thing.
check if the me.dirty property is true; 
Yes : confirm exit or continue editing 
No : drop it like a hot potato and close out the form. with me.undo and a NoSave just for kicks. –
and before saving the record... do another check. to see if txtSSN is blank.

Comment: If I put the code in AfterUpdate, if the field is blank it does not trigger anything to run, so it doesn't give an error if the SSN is blank asking what the user wants to do.  I think it's because a blank field wasn't updated, so there's no after update.  I've been playing with this so much.  There has to be a way to do it!  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user3033348 on the Form_BeforeUpdate; you could have a bit of code to ensure that the txtSSN is filled before it can save. With error message and setfocus to the point after it exits

Comment: I moved the code to go with the field txtSSN.  So it fills in before running Before Update code, on Key Down, I have it fill in txtSSN with 000000000 - works. But the Before Update code doesn't run.  I've been researching the order that the Events run in, and it should work.  Key Down 1st, and then Before Update 2nd.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a check against existing SSN in the database to see if such an SSN is already in the database.
Sounds like you got this beat !

Comment: Already do that just didn't show code.  Thanks everyone for your help but I'm giving up.  I changed it so it says that the SSN can't be blank and just goes to the SSN field.  If the user wants to cancel, they could just hit the cancel button.  One more step for the user, but 3 forums later, we can't figure it out.  I appreciate all your suggestions!

Comment: @user3033348 You could have a counter to see how many times the User left the SSN blank. A different message for every attempt to leave the SSN field blank is increasing in urgency. eg You really shouldn't leave it blank.... I can't accept a blank SSN ....... and If you leave it blank there is no point of using this form. and once they hit the limit close the form out.